# Confusion between topology and sigma-algebra

Tags: analysis

I'm confused by definitions in ["Real and Complex analysis" by Walter Rudin,3rd].

For empty set $\emptyset$ in topology $\tau$ and sigma-algebra $\Sigma$ of a set $X$:
$$
\emptyset \in \tau \\
\emptyset \in \Sigma \text{ since } \emptyset \in X^c
$$
But many places said that:$\emptyset \in \Sigma$ with no conditions.Why?

For union sets:
$$
\text{any element in } \{V_{\alpha}\}\text{ is also in } \tau,\text{then } \bigcup_{\alpha}{V_{\alpha}} \in \tau
\\ 
A_n \in \Sigma \text{ for } n=1,2,\ldots,n,\text{ then } \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n} \in \Sigma
$$ 
What's different between two describtions,the order by 'n' means something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this first part, $\emptyset \in \Sigma$ is just a direct consequence of the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra as you stated. My guess (as I dont have that book) is that they don't actually prove this fact every time but rather treat it as a definition for convenience.

For the latter, a topology is closed under arbitrary unions of sets, while in a $\sigma$-algebra you require the union to be countable (hence the numbering $1, \dots, \infty$).

Answer (score 1):

An example :
$$\mathfrak{B} :=\{B \subset \mathbb {R} \mid B \; \text{is countable} \lor \mathbb {R}\setminus B \; \text{is countable}\}$$
We have
$$\forall B_n \in \mathfrak {B} \Rightarrow \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n \in \mathfrak {B}$$ 
but 
$$\bigcup\limits_{x\in \mathbb {R^+}}\{x\}=\mathbb {R^+} \notin \mathfrak {B}$$

$(\mathbb R, \mathfrak B)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra but not a topology.